# How to understand c++ coroutines programming intuitively?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I've read something about c++ coroutines ([tutorial](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/c++-coroutines.html), [implement](https://lewissbaker.github.io/)), but not fully understand. I am wondering how to read the examples provided in concepts of c++ source code?

Like, an example from [tutorial](https://www.scs.stanford.edu/%7Edm/blog/c++-coroutines.html)

```
template<typename PromiseType>
struct GetPromise {
  PromiseType *p_;
  bool await_ready() { return false; } // says yes call await_suspend
  bool await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<PromiseType> h) {
    p_ = &h.promise();
    return false;     // says no don't suspend coroutine after all
  }
  PromiseType *await_resume() { return p_; }
};

struct ReturnObject3 {
  struct promise_type {
    unsigned value_;

    ReturnObject3 get_return_object() {
      return ReturnObject3 {
        .h_ = std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(*this)
      };
    }
    std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
    std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
    void unhandled_exception() {}
  };

  std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> h_;
  operator std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>() const { return h_; }
};

ReturnObject3
counter3()
{
  auto pp = co_await GetPromise<ReturnObject3::promise_type>{};

  for (unsigned i = 0;; ++i) {
    pp->value_ = i;
    co_await std::suspend_always{};
  }
}

void
main3()
{
  std::coroutine_handle<ReturnObject3::promise_type> h = counter3();
  ReturnObject3::promise_type &promise = h.promise();
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    std::cout << "counter3: " << promise.value_ << std::endl;
    h();
  }
  h.destroy();
}
```

1. The `ReturnObject3::promise_type` was created immediately after `counter3(){`, how the compiler knew that this type of promise_type was to be created? Suppose it was deduced by return type of `ReturnObject3`, but it seemed that return type has not been included in function signature?
2. If it was not a coroutine, the `ReturnObject3` object would be supposed to be returned at the end of the function. But in coroutine cases, it could be returned at any time (by coroutine primitives). How to describe functions of return type and return value? For example, in `counter3()`, the `ReturnObject3` object returned by 1st `co_await suspend_always{}` and then has been destructed immediately in `main3()`. What happened for remaining `co_await suspend_always{}` when i = {1, 2, ...}, returned nothing or something only compiler or lib knew?
3. In line `co_await GetPromise<ReturnObject3::promise_type>{}`, the handle created for `ReturnObject3::promise_type` has been set in `GetPromise::await_suspend(...)` automatically. How compiler knew they were connected (ReturnObject, GetPromise, handle)? Is there the rule that (at least) one handle bound to one coroutine?

Questions mentioned above are just examples. What I want to ask it that, how to understand the set of ideas of coroutine programming in concepts of application code intuitively?

Comment: "*not fully understand*" The code seems to be pretty terrible. It's a bad way to use the system. Indeed, if you see someone explicitly using `co_await std::always_suspend` in a coroutine like this, there's generally some hackery going on. The tutorial calls the design "clunky", but this is only because they insist on using it in a clunky way.

Comment: 1. It comes from the `std::coroutine_traits<ReturnObject3>::promise_type` which you omitted from the sample. 2. You destructed the `ReturnObject3` but the `ReturnObject3::promise_type` still exists in the coroutine. 3. The compiler uses the coroutine handle for the calling coroutine. Note also that if you have a question about a tutorial, you might want to ask the author of the tutorial.